# Rendering data to html in flask: how to pass a data through app.route function flask?

Tags: python, function, flask, render-html

I have a function in which i get all calculation stuff, and i want to render these calculation stuff on my dashboard. i am unable to load my dashboard page when i pass (input:dict) to main_function(), 
I want to render my dashboard with these data, and then i can use jinja stuff on html to catch these values there. Tried many methods. Any expert Please..

Thanks

```
imports ...
from other file import other_functions
from other file import other_functions_2
from other file import other_functions_3
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates/')
@app.route("/dashboard")
def calculate_full_eva_web(input:dict):
   calculate_gap = other_functions(input)
   calculate_matrix = other_functions_2(input)
   average = other_functions_3(input)
   data = dict{'calculate_gap':calculate_gap, 'calculate_matrix':calculate_matrix,'average':average}
   return render_template('pages/dashboard.html', data = data) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

Error.
Traceback:
TypeError: calculate_full_eva_web() missing 1 required positional argument: 'input'
```

[image: TRACEBACK]

Comment: You need to show the full traceback

Comment: @roganjosh sure uploading

Comment: @roganjosh check please

Comment: That's no use to me because it doesn't show a single part of your own code that triggers the exception; everything is coming from `site-packages` so you're only showing how the library has failed to process your input... which isn't shown in that

Comment: `calculate_full_evaluation_web` is almost certainly your own function, but you haven't shown that. This issue is in your own code, it's not something from Flask/Jinja, it looks like a basic Python error

Comment: @roganjosh please can you check it now , to be specific i want to render the data with html, which data  ? the data which is calculated in calculate_full_eval_web()

Comment: @roganjosh please can recheck the code .

Comment: Right, now I see the issue. You need to show your template. Presumably you have a form that calls that particular route, but you're not passing the argument there

Comment: @roganjosh the template is already in my code , i did'nt showed in my post before because it is very basic thing i know flask binds to templates folder and i have templates, but i edited my post and added templates which belongs to app. and also app.run(). The issue is when i didnt pass data in to calculate_full_eva_web, the flask is able to render my dashboard but when i pass data in calculate_full_eva_web. is throws error.